# Restore Single App Purchase iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am in the process of developing a free app with the ability to purchase a yearly subscription that will unlock the full content. For the last couple weeks I have been switching between reading the apple site and looking up tutorials that better explain how to accomplish this process. I have ran through the page with a test account and the payment process is working, the only problem I am having is validating that the user has paid before I access this page.

The page I am using to connect to the Apple store is a UIViewController called `PurchaserViewController` and this page is not accessed until after the user is asked to subscribe. According to the Apple site:

> Unlocking App Functionality
> If the product enables app functionality, set a Boolean value to enable the code path and update your user interface as needed. To determine what functionality to unlock, **consult the persistent record that your app made when the transaction occurred**. Your app needs to update this Boolean value whenever a purchase is completed and at app launch.

From my understanding they are refering to the app receipt system, but I am confused because the Apple developer site mentions all these tools and things to accomplish your goals, but does not give you examples or shows you how to implement them.

> For non-consumable products and auto-renewable subscriptions in iOS 7 and later, use the app receipt as your persistent record.

At first I thought this step would be as simple as setting an NSUserDefaults in the `paymentQueue` and updating it should their subscription expire. When I looked online for receipt validation I get articles on restoring locally, restoring online through the app store, encoding and decoding the receipt, validating that the receipt was signed by apple and that it references my app... At this point I forget what I am even trying to accomplish.

Is there a simple way that I can restore a single app purchase, so that when the user logs into the app it does not prompt them with the `Confirm Subscription - Do you want to subscribe to *product* for *duration* for *price*?` and when they click `Confirm` -> `You're currently subscribed to this.`

So far this is my `PurchaserViewController.m`, and to access it I have a push button segue on my main `ViewController.m` page:

```
#import "PurchaserViewController.h"

@interface PurchaserViewController ()
@end

@implementation PurchaserViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        NSLog(@"Parental-controls are disabled");

        //product name replaced with 1
        SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"1"]];
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [productsRequest start];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Parental-controls are enabled");
    }
}

- (IBAction)purchase:(SKProduct *)product {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = (int)[response.products count];
    if (count > 0) {
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        [self purchase:validProduct];
        NSLog(@"self purchase validProduct");
    } else if (!validProduct) {
        NSLog(@"No products available");
    }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        NSLog(@"paymentQueue");
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"Should work now!");

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Work once again!");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"Error encountered");
                }

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

In other words, how do I verify that a user did purchase? Is setting something under user defaults at the time of purchase viable? But if so, how do I make it expire and re-check it, or restore it should they re-install the app? How do I locate the receipt or ask apple for proof of purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ViewController.m` file, include in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) { NSLog(@"No local receipt -- handle the error."); } else { NSLog(@"Local Receipt Found"); }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I am checking if the receipt is found locally, if it isn't then they haven't purchased, if it is then I must validate it?

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for, the next step in the process would be to validate the receipt, although the company I am working for has decided to make the app free. For now I do not need to investigate it any more.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a non-renewable subscription. The receipt is not the place to persist this according to Apple's StoreKitGuide. Here's what they say:

**For non-renewing subscriptions, use iCloud or your own server to keep a persistent record.**

You can find this on page 26 of the pdf version of that document.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was using a non-consumable renewing subscription. The auto-renew happens yearly. Although the company I am working for opted to put this on hold for another year, and instead make it completely free.

Comment: I guess the idea is if it's non-renewing this is not recorded in the receipt. They only record it at time of purchase. So you would need to track that information yourself outside of the app like a server. Non-consumable purchases are always stored in the receipt even if you refresh the receipt. Anyhow, I guess you don't need to worry about it for now.